# why is my postmeta table is so heavy

Tags: post-meta, mysql

One of my database is realy heavy (+100Mo) for a site with not so many content (like 40 pages & 10 posts)).
I found in phpmyadmin that my table "postmeta" is 95Mo.
So i wonder to know what are the data that takes so many place... !

i run a DB optimizer plugin ([Advanced Database Cleaner](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-database-cleaner/))
that help me go down to 92Mo, for only 2261 rows in table. ( Before, whas much more but i don't remember the number of lines ).

usualy my WP postmeta table is 2 to 5 mo for 4k rows...

I thinks this is linked to my theme, but i have no idea how to know wich data is so heavy. So how can i know wich are the heavy lines in my database ?

in text export, the more biggest rows is like this : (maybe it can help ?)
https://pastebin.com/DMRQw3mD

Comment: You're going to have to look inside that table and figure out what the biggest post meta key/value pairs are. That would be a MySQL dev ops question. It may be that it's just how your site works with the various plugins it has. Eitherway there's very little that people can advise without direct access to the table, or, information about its contents beyond the size of the table as a whole

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by 4k lines? I assume by Mo you mean Mb? How many rows are in the table? What's the most common meta keys?

Comment: 4k lines is 4k rows. Sorry for m'y english !

Comment: Would you like an export of the table ?

Comment: That might be a data breach if you shared that publicly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the Page builder plugins records page/post specific data in the meta data of the Post/Page which is saved in wp_postmeta table. Similarly, you are using Elementor Pro plugin which is saving post configuration data there.

IMO, You should not be worried about this data otherwise you can contact plugin author to optimize it.